# Android device as wifi access point

Tags: android, wifi

I am building an application where the mobile (where i install the app) will act as the access point and another wifi hardware that has to pair to this device(`network/access point`).

Could someone give me an input on how to go about it ?

Can you give samples ..it would be really helpful...

Comment: Could you please post how you solve the problem? I find myself Google about it but can't get valuable results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its called Mobile AP. and its available on many android devices

```
Settings > Wifi Setting > Mobile AP
```

Comment: ok...i understood the logic... Now can u tell me if there is any way to find out(programmatically.. any api or samples) if the connection has been established with the device if we are keeping the mobile device as an access point. the wifi controller or module that i will be getting from a vendor will be programmed to connect to the default access point.

Comment: [That is a vast topic](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html). A little google searching will get you your answers. Its also answered here on Stack Overflow